# Real line and the Sorgenfrey line have the same dense subsets

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line, dense-subspaces

I am trying to prove that the real line and the Sorgenfrey line have the same dense subsets. That is, $A\subset \Bbb R$ is dense under the lower limit topology if and only if it is dense under the usual topology.

I know that a dense set is defined as:

> Let $(X, \tau )$ be a topological. We say that $D \subset X$ is dense in $X$ se $\overline{D} = X$.

My idea would be to maybe show that: (1) any set A dense in the real line is also dense in the Sorgenfrey line, (2) any set A dense in the Sorgenfrey line is also dense in the real line. But I'm not sure how to do this. Any help?

Comment: The same dense?

Comment: Yes, for example if a set A is dense in R, then it is also dense in Rs

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it clearer. Please check to see that I did not make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote real line by $\mathbb{R}$ and Sorgenfrey line by $\mathbb{R'}$. Then we have to prove that an arbitrary dense set $\mathbb{A}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R'}$ iff it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Step 1) Assume A is dense in $\mathbb{R'}$. We will prove A is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ be an arbitrary open set. Then $[x-\epsilon/2,x+\epsilon/2)$ contains an element 'a' from $\mathbb{A}$. This implies $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains 'a'. This proves our case.

Step 2) The other way round follows a very similar argument.

Comment: You're not quite there. What if $a = x - \epsilon/2$?

Comment: It would still be contained in $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ as $x-\epsilon/2 \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Silly me!  . . . . . . .

Comment: Step 2) given A dense in R, let $[x,x+\epsilon)$ be open in R'. Then $(x,x+\epsilon)$ contains a point of A, done.

Comment: Thanks for completing it!!